# How can I tell if my shrimp is pregnant?

Tags: fish, breeding

Two of my five ghost shrimp are really bloated. They have no trouble staying at the bottom of the tank.

Are they pregnant? What is up?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

If she's pregnant, she will normally hold a clutch of eggs and later the hatched babies below her hind swimmerets.

Example: [image: Pregnant Ghost Shrimp]

Answer (score 0):

Um, I have pregnant shrimp, she has really bloated belly, (I have 2 pregnant Sunkists and 1 red cherry) and I check their bellies every day, you may see, (yellow white and various colors for species) small balls and with a thin string attached to the mother, and about 8-24 (Depending on species) also you might notice that they have lost their saddle!

Answer (score 0):

If the belly is bloated, it may be that they are being over-fed. If you see ball shaped specks in the belly, that means they are pregnant. This is a photo of my pregnant sunkist shrimp. [image: my pregnant sunkist shrimp]

It hard to see since it’s yellow to yellow but hope this picture helps with understanding how shrimp eggs look like!